# Include not working with Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I'm not sure what changed, but, after coming back to an application I was working on a few weeks ago, my `.Include()` call is no longer working for for one of my related tables.  The weird part is that it works for a different table.  Here is some code with comments showing what my results are:

```
//Get the order and nothing else.
using (OrderEntity orderContext = new OrderEntity(OrdersConnectionString)) {
    var query = from order in orderContext.ShippingOrders
                where order.ShipperId == shippingId
                select order;

    //I got a value!
    shippingOrder = query.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
}

//Get the line item and nothing else.
using (OrderEntity orderContext = new OrderEntity(OrdersConnectionString)) {
    var query = from orderItem in orderContext.ShippingOrderItems
                where orderItem.ShipperId == shippingId
                select orderItem;

    //I got a value!
    shippingOrderItems = query.ToList();
}
```

Here is where I am confused:

```
//Get the order *AND* the line item
using (OrderEntity orderContext = new OrderEntity(OrdersConnectionString)) {
    var query = from order in orderContext.ShippingOrders.Include("ShippingOrderItems")
                where order.ShipperId == shippingId
                select order;

    //I get a ShippingOrder result, but no items are returned.  I used the SQL Server Profiler and saw the SQL that got executed; it contains the item, EF just isn't loading the object.
    shippingOrder = query.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I am able to get back results for a different related table.  This makes me think that the EF is missing the relationship between my order and line item table, but, I'm not sure how I can fix that.

**Edit**:  Here is the Order Entity

```
/// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="OrderModel", Name="ShippingOrder")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class ShippingOrder : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new ShippingOrder object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="shipperId">Initial value of the ShipperId property.</param>
    public static ShippingOrder CreateShippingOrder(global::System.String shipperId)
    {
        ShippingOrder shippingOrder = new ShippingOrder();
        shippingOrder.ShipperId = shipperId;
        return shippingOrder;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String ShipperId
    {
        get
        {
            return _ShipperId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ShipperId != value)
            {
                OnShipperIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("ShipperId");
                _ShipperId = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
                ReportPropertyChanged("ShipperId");
                OnShipperIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _ShipperId;
    partial void OnShipperIdChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnShipperIdChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String OrderNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _OrderNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            OnOrderNumberChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("OrderNumber");
            _OrderNumber = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("OrderNumber");
            OnOrderNumberChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _OrderNumber;
    partial void OnOrderNumberChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnOrderNumberChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Nullable<global::System.DateTime> OrderDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _OrderDate;
        }
        set
        {
            OnOrderDateChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("OrderDate");
            _OrderDate = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("OrderDate");
            OnOrderDateChanged();
        }
    }
    private Nullable<global::System.DateTime> _OrderDate;
    partial void OnOrderDateChanging(Nullable<global::System.DateTime> value);
    partial void OnOrderDateChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String CustomsComment
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomsComment;
        }
        set
        {
            OnCustomsCommentChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("CustomsComment");
            _CustomsComment = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("CustomsComment");
            OnCustomsCommentChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _CustomsComment;
    partial void OnCustomsCommentChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnCustomsCommentChanged();

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("OrderModel", "FK_ShippingOrderItem_ShippingOrder", "ShippingOrderItem")]
    public EntityCollection<ShippingOrderItem> ShippingOrderItems
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<ShippingOrderItem>("OrderModel.FK_ShippingOrderItem_ShippingOrder", "ShippingOrderItem");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<ShippingOrderItem>("OrderModel.FK_ShippingOrderItem_ShippingOrder", "ShippingOrderItem", value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("OrderModel", "FK_ShippingOrderItemTracking_ShippingOrder", "ShippingOrderTracking")]
    public EntityCollection<ShippingOrderTracking> ShippingOrderTrackings
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<ShippingOrderTracking>("OrderModel.FK_ShippingOrderItemTracking_ShippingOrder", "ShippingOrderTracking");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<ShippingOrderTracking>("OrderModel.FK_ShippingOrderItemTracking_ShippingOrder", "ShippingOrderTracking", value);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Long shot... have you got an empty constructor on your ShippingOrderItem(s) class?

Comment: Can you post the ShippingOrder entity?  What is the name of the property (and configuration) of the ShippingOrderItem?

Comment: @PhilCartmell - Just an FYI: I am using the auto-generated code (database-first).  I looked at the class and there is no constructor specified, so, C# magic is leaving me with an empty constructor.

Comment: @dtryon - I posted the class for the order entity (I did removed some properties for brevity; the navigational properties are all there).

Comment: If you put a try{} catch (Exception e) {} around shippingOrder = query.ToList().FirstOrDefault(); maybe its throwing some sort of exception?

Comment: Have you used something like http://efprof.com to inspect the actual SQL that is being generated?  Wild guess, something changed on the database side so your queries aren't executing the way you think they should be.

Comment: @CodingGorilla - I have used SQL Server Profiler to look at the SQL that is being executed.  While it looks ugly, it does execute without any errors.  The data for my line-item is within the resultset.

Comment: @PhilCartmell - No exceptions are being thrown.  :(

Comment: So then are you saying that your `Order.LineItems` collection is empty?

Comment: @CodingGorilla - Yes.  I get an order returned, it's the line items that are not.  Sorry if I was not clear enough with that.

Comment: Have you tried just refreshing the model from the database to make sure something on the database side hasn't changed?

Comment: @CodingGorilla - I did refresh the model.  I was hoping that would fix it, but, no dice.  I'm really confused why the actual SQL that EF is executing shows the results I need for the line-items, but, it's just not populating the navigational property.

Comment: Yea, I'm out of ideas.  You might have to contact MS support on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the cause of the issue was.  I decided to just drop my database and re-create my tables (along with the primary and foreign keys) and migrate over all the data again.  It actually fixed it, but, I'm not sure what ended up being different.  I was not getting any exceptions logged and based on the SQL Server Profiler it looked like the correct query was being executed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I meant to come back and accept this as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Lol.. well, better late than never! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
if (Order.shippingId != null && Order.shippingId > 0)
    orderContext.LoadProperty(Orders, Order => Order.ShippingOrderItems);
```

This will fetch the matching order id in ShippingOrderItems.